# How to fix segmentation fault in this code

Tags: c

This is linked list program no error but output not showing properly
   no error but i think logic is not ok implement this without using   function only logic is require.

```
struct node * c;
struct node * head;

int n, i = 0;
scan("%d", & n);
if (n < 10) {

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        struct node * p;
        p = (struct node * ) malloc(size of (struct node));

        scan("%d", & p - > data);
        p - > next = NULL;

        c = NULL;

        head = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = p;
        } else {

            c = head;
            while (c - > next != NULL) {

                c = c - > next;
            }
            c - > next = p;
            print("%d", c - > next);

            struct node * d = head;
            while (d != NULL) {
                print("%d", d - > data);
                d = d - > next;
            }

        }
}
```

This is linked list program and i added code part not entire block

expected result if input 10 20 30
output 10->20->30

Comment: Please indent your code. Learn to respect your code first.

Comment: If there’s no error, how does the segfault relate to this? Also run the code line by line in a debugger. It has several issues which need to be fixed for it to be rational and you’ll see them that way if looking at the code doesn’t show them.

Comment: You can add some more new lines when printing and some spaces after the values. Also, what is the definition for ```struct node```?

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see.

```
    head = NULL;
```

You are initializing `head` to `NULL` each time inside the for loop.
You should initialize while declaring.

```
struct node * head = NULL;
```

Also

Move your printing code outside the `for` loop.

```
    struct node * d = head;
    while (d != NULL) {
        print("%d", d - > data);
        d = d - > next;
    }
```

Comment: After doing all these step output is not coming only some address is coming out

Comment: You are printing address here `print("%d", c - > next);` that too using `%d`.